# Apptitude - Have I removed my entire system?

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, aptitude

I was trying to remove an unused package via Aptitude interface but I seem to have removed my entire system? Luckily my personal data is backed up. Aptitude ran for about 10 minutes or so listing everything it was removing, then the screen went black and has been like that for about 30 mins now?

I do not know what I did but definitely does not look good ...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Running:
Xubuntu 13.10
64-bit

Comment: What was the name of the unused package you removed?

Comment: I was trying to remove Gimp Save for Web, it was marked as obsolete, but it is my first time using Aptitude, so not entirely sure that is what i did :(

Comment: can you login to consol?

Comment: if you do try to reconfigure `xorg` `sudo /etc/init.d/xdm stop` then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` after `sudo /etc/init.d/xdm start`

Comment: I have a black screen no GUI and no key commands work. I have not tried a reboot yet.

Comment: you should ligin to tty terminal Ctrl+Alt+F1 not Ctrl+Alt+T

Comment: I would just reboot, I think, and go from there. At the moment you are in limbo - or more likely some infinite loop of badly written code!

Comment: try reconfigure your display as I provided and see the next

Comment: @JohnnyD. perl: Setting locale failed. debconf: Unable to to initialize frontend: Dialog. No useable dialog-like program is installed. Unable to to initialize frontend: Readline. Cant locate Term/Readline.pm ... Falling back to frontend: Teletype. /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfgure: xserver-xorg is broken or not fully installed.

Comment: If `apt-get` works, you may be able to reinstall with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` - leave it until it has finished, then when you are sure it has finished, reboot.

Comment: try installing desktop indeed :) and if it still will not work reconfigure then

Answer (score 0):

If `apt-get` works, you may be able to reinstall with `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` - leave it until it has finished, then when you are sure it has finished, reboot.

[`xubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/xubuntu-desktop) installs all the things needed as dependencies, so it should reinstall the basics required for the Xubuntu system to run.

Comment: E: Unmet Dependencies. Try apt_get -f install. Shall I go with that?

Comment: What unmet dependences? You might as well try `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: Gives big list of Recommends inc net-work,ttf,xfce4,thunar ...

Comment: Rebooted - now stuck in grub page.

Comment: Try boot-repair.

Comment: Grub says; Minimal Bash-Like editing line editing is supported. `Boot` gets Error: you need to load the kernel first.

Comment: Now on `live CD` ran `Boot Repair`, it did not fix the grub. Should I carry on my post here or start a new one? http://paste.ubuntu.com/6987192/

Comment: Probably... How it managed to muck up Grub I don't know.... The Boot Repair log *I think* looks OK, so it may be something else... if you do start elsewhere, adding the content `/etc/default/grub` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`  may be of help.